# newb: what is the correct/recommended directory hierarchy of CodeIgniter+Tank_Auth

Tags: codeigniter, directory, hierarchy

What is the correct/recommended directory structure for CodeIgniter+Tank_Auth?

Ilya Konyukhov, author of Tank_Auth, at http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/ writes:

"Copy the application folder content to your CI application folder."

Does this mean

1) the Tank_Auth application folder is to become a subdirectory of the CI application folder

or

2) contents of each of the Tank_Auth directories is to be merged with the corresponding directories in CI?

The reason I ask is that:

1) when using the CI distro's application/controllers/welcome.php, CI works as expected

2) when that file is replaced with the corresponding file from Tank_Auth, only a blank screen is produced.

Log level 4 doesn't reveal anything interesting :(

THANKS for helping this newb learn about CI+T_A.

regards/ldv

Answer (score 0):

You have to merge the folders, so, 2)

Make sure you don't delete any file when merging (by replacing folders with files inside, in example).

If you overwrote the controller welcome.php, you should be redirected to /auth/login automatically. If this doesn't happen, something went wrong with the merging. Check also if you've setup the config file for Tank_auth correctly (points 4, 5, 6).